# Determine whether a jQuery selection is in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a jQuery selection that either originated as a newly created element (e.g. `$("<div/>")`) and has no parent, or is actually an element in the DOM.

What's the most efficient way to determine whether or not the selected element is actually in the current DOM tree?

One possibility is to call `.parent()`, but I suspect there's a more efficient way.

Comment: If you're trying to make your javascript run faster this is not going to make much difference. You need to do some profiling work first and see what's actually slow. Calling parent() a hundred times won't even take a millisecond.

Comment: @Mike, that depends on how often I'm going to need to call the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that both my question and Andy's solution (using `node.parentNode`) can be generalized. Here's a full version that will work for any jQuery selection, even if it has at least one ancestor.

```
/**
 * Returns true if this selection is part of the current DOM;
 * false if it's a fragment.
 * @return {Boolean}
 */
jQuery.fn.inDom = function() {
    // Get the first element in the jQuery selection
    var node = this[0];

    while (node) {
        if (node.nodeType === Node.DOCUMENT_NODE) {
            return true;
        }
        node = node.parentNode;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The idea to ask for a `.parent()` is not that bad, actually its a pretty common way. Anyway, you could also use the `.contains()` method.

```
var newdiv = $('<div>');

if( $.contains(document.body, newdiv[0]) ) {
}
```

reference: [.contains()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/)

example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/gGPav/

performance: http://jsperf.com/contains-vs-parentnode

looking at the performance, I would also go with `node.parentNode`

Comment: Just checking for `.parentNode` is not accurate. The element may be inside another element that __isn't__ in the DOM. You should check up to `document.documentElement`.

Comment: I realized that and added my own answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [jQuery index method](http://api.jquery.com/index/).

Something like `$(yourDiv).index('body div')` can tell you a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Give the newly created element an ID and query for the ID.

Comment: How would you identify it from the other DIVs in this case? Something needs to be unique.